# Rails after_save and after_commit callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I went through difference in after_save and after_commit callbacks in rails and major difference I found is after_commit calls both on create and update,is there a way to call after_commit only on create??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify that the callback should only be fired by a certain action with the :on option:

```
after_commit :do_foo, on: :create
after_commit :do_bar, on: :update
after_commit :do_baz, on: :destroy

after_commit :do_foo_bar, on: [:create, :update]
after_commit :do_bar_baz, on: [:update, :destroy]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrect about the difference between the two callbacks.  `after_save` is invoke when an object is created and updated, unless constrained as @Grammakov pointed out.  `after_commit` fires on `create`, `update` and `destroy`.

The main difference is `after_save` invokes immediately after the model object `save` method completes, where `after_commit` doesn't fire until record is actually committed to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

```
after_create_commit :trigger

private
  def trigger
   # Your Code
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The other big difference is that after_save takes place in the same transaction as the create/save.  This means that if there is an error the object is not created/saved.  It also means that the row or table that the create/save is taking place on will be locked until the after_save completes.  This can cause db performance issues or deadlocks.  Particularly when you have several after_save call backs.  In general, I default to using after_commit unless I have a good reason to do otherwise.